# RDF Parse Error: Element or attribute "http:" do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName:)?NCName

Tags: import, rdf, graphdb

I just created a new Ontotext DB, and I'm trying to import an rdf file into the DB.

The files comes from an official institutional site.

The content is (first three lines):

```
<http://dati.camera.it/ocd/persona.rdf/p301553> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>    "Red John"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
<http://dati.camera.it/ocd/persona.rdf/p25460>  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/gender>  "male" .
<http://dati.camera.it/ocd/persona.rdf/p300460> <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> "John Doe" .
```

and I received the following error on the first line:

```
 RDF Parse Error: Element or attribute "http:" do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName:)?NCName. [line 1, column 7]
```

So, the question is: how can I set/match a `QName production` on `Ontotext` when importing an external resource?

Comment: can be a bit more specific please? You load which dataset from which link how exactly into GraphDB?

Comment: Very likely, the file extension does not match the actual rdf file format, e.g. a turtle or ntriples rdf data in a file with extension .rdf or .xml instead of .ttl or .nt ...